# How to add new device to adhoc provisioning profile?

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile

I am searching where I can add new device to an existing adhoc profile, I cannot find it. There has been some updates on the provisioning website. Many thanks.

Comment: What I did finally in order to make the newly added devices compatible I have created a new provisioning profile.Anyone facing the same problem. I have logge din as Team Agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the new device UUID to the device section of the web site.
2. Then goto the provisioning section. Goto the Adhoc provision that needs the new device.
3. select the new device you added in step 1.  It should be there.
4. Now you have to generate and download the provisioning file again and distribute it to all the people that will be beta testing your app.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply but i cannot see anywhere where to select the devices when you edit a provisioning profile.

Comment: Hello thanks its working on Firefox i can see the devices when i edit. but not on chrome :) -- i cannot see the devices list.

Comment: @veereef no problem. Anytime.